# Jumpy/incorrect looking spectrograph on iOS5

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I have written a function to perform an FFT on an array of 1024 samples. I am attempting use the output of this function to plot a spectrogram.

The graph has very inconsistent input, spending most of its time at 0, and when it is showing something seems to have very little relation to the music at all. I have included two screenshots to demonstrate.

I have included a couple of screenshots, and the code used to perform the FFT. Does anyone have any ideas for why the produced output is so bad?

Also, I've noticed that the low end of the spectrogram is "peaky", as in it likes to jump a lot.

Strange output:


[image: Sometimes some output is, but the magnitudes don't look right]

No output (occurs 1/2 to 2/3rds of all drawn frames):


[image: For maybe 1/2 to 2/3rds of the time, no output is shown]

The code:

```
// Get the samples

AudioSampleType *samples = [_songModel nextSamplesWithLength: _fftN];
if (samples == nil)
    return nil;

// Convert AudioSampleTypes (SInt16s) into floats between -1.0 and 1.0 
// (required by the DSP library).

for (int i = 0; i < _fftN; i++)
    _inputReal[i] = (samples[i] + 0.5) / 32767.5;

// Window the input

vDSP_vmul(_inputReal, 1, _hanningWindow, 1, _windowedReal, 1, _fftN);

// Convert our real input into even-odd form

vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)_windowedReal, 2, &_fourierOutput, 1, _fftHalfN);

// Perform the fast fourier transform

vDSP_fft_zrip(_fftSetup, &_fourierOutput, 1, _fftLog2n, FFT_FORWARD);

// Calculate magnitudes (will output to the real part of the COMPLEX_SPLIT)

vDSP_zvmags(&_fourierOutput, 1, _fourierOutput.realp, 1, _fftHalfN);

// Build and return the input and output of the analysis

return [[FrequencyData alloc] initWithSignal:_inputReal 
                                signalLength:_fftN  
                         frequencyMagnitudes:_fourierOutput.realp
                             magnitudeLength:_fftHalfN];
```

#### Edit

Setup code:

```
_fftN = 1 << _fftLog2n;
_fftHalfN = _fftN / 2;
_stride = 1;

_fourierOutput.realp = (float *) malloc(_fftHalfN * sizeof(float));
_fourierOutput.imagp = (float *) malloc(_fftHalfN * sizeof(float));

_hanningWindow = (float *) malloc(_fftN * sizeof(float));    
vDSP_hann_window(_hanningWindow, _fftN, 0);

_inputReal = (float *) malloc(_fftN * sizeof(float));
_windowedReal = (float *) malloc(_fftN * sizeof(float));
_fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(_fftLog2n, FFT_RADIX2);
```

Comment: To debug, you could try replacing your song model with a sinewave generator of a known frequency, and/or plotting the waveform as well as the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

The results with no output are likely due to a bug somewhere else in your code (perhaps in the song reading or plotting code).

The "strange output" can be the correct FFT result for recorded music, as the complete audio spectrum of interesting sounding musical instruments and voices can be very different from just the notated pitch frequencies.